# How to mock IO::Socket::INET with Test::MockObject

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm writing some unit tests for a Perl module that uses IO::Socket::INET, so I'd like to mock out the IO::Socket::INET module using Test::MockObject.

Sp far I have something like

```
$INC{'IO/Socket/INET.pm'} = 1;
my $inet = Test::MockObject->new();
$inet->fake_module('IO::Socket::INET', new => sub { $inet });
```

but the code in the module I'm testing has code like

```
my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new(...);
my $data = <$server>
```

and when I run the test I get an error like "Not a GLOB reference" when it tries to execute the angle operator.

What do I need to add to make my mock object reference look like a file handle so that this code runs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) to make your own mock INET class that will provide its own implementation of the `<>` operator. Something like the following:

```
package My::MockINET;

use strict;
use warnings;

use overload '<>' => \&_readline;

sub new { 
    return bless { }, shift;
}

sub _readline { 
    return "some data here\n";
}

1;
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$INC{'IO/Socket/INET.pm'} = 1;
my $inet = My::MockINET->new();

my $data = <$inet>;
```

Comment: thanks, I've found a way to do it with Test::MockObject now. You can pass a glob reference to the MockObject constructor, so I create a file handle using open(FH, "<", \$scalar) and then pass \\*FH to MockObject->new(). The mocked object then behaves like a file handle.